# Attach to terminal buffer opened with termopen

Tags: neovim, lua

I have the following Lua function:

```
local function submit_diff(diff_msg_file)
  vim.fn.termopen("arc diff HEAD^ -F " .. diff_msg_file, {
    on_exit = function(_, exit_code, _)
      if exit_code == 0 then
        vim.loop.fs_unlink(diff_msg_file)
      end
    end,
  })
end
```

This does almost everything I want. It:

1. Runs the command `arc diff` with the appropriate arguments
2. I can delete the file speficied as an argument if the terminal command exits succesfully

The one problem is that no window is opened. The command being run is interactive, so I can't see what's going on since the buffer created by `termopen` doesn't seem to automatically create and attach to its own window.

Is there a way for me to either find the buffer created by termopen and then create a window to attach it to, or call termopen in such a way a window is created with the buffer attach, or should I be using something other than termopen?

Comment: In short, you can use the Neovim API `nvim_buf_call` to call `termopen` inside the callback (sure you need to load the `buf` you passing into `nvim_buf_call` into a window beforehand. (I was just solving a similar problem and got an answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me here was to actually switch to just issuing a `:term` command. This meant I couldn't get a callback when the command finished, but I moved the cleanup work that I wanted to do into the actual term command itself. I made sure it was only run on success by using the `&&` shell command.

```
local function submit_diff(diff_msg_file)
  vim.cmd("vsplit | term arc diff HEAD^ -F " .. diff_msg_file .. " && rm " .. diff_msg_file)
end
```